# pythonwhois returns none value for contact information for specific tlds like .io and .it

Tags: python, whois

I used `get_whois(domain)` function of *pythonwhois 2.4.3* for retrieving whois information for domains.

But when I enter domains with specific tlds (like *dexi.io* or *securiteam.it*) the output returns None for contact information.

In other words, for example when I use

```
get_whois('dexi.io')
```

it returns a record like below:

```
'contacts': {'admin': None, 'tech': None, 'registrant': None, 'billing': None}
```

Comment: Please remove the `dns` tag, as your question is not related to this protocol.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in `https://github.com/joepie91/python-whois/blob/master/pythonwhois/parse.py` the software is based on a bunch of regexes.

This can make it unable to parse some cases, maybe because it is missing the specific format used by a given registry, or just because things have changed. First course of action would be to make sure to install the latest version of the tool, and then if it is still actively maintained, try to contact its author or the community around it.

Also for `dexi.io` if you do a whois query on it you will see absolutely no data about contacts, like a thin registry. So no tool woul be able to give you that information in that specific case. The tool will need to be able (some are some don't) to gather the correct whois server to query in a second time by parsing the `Registrar WHOIS Server` field in the first reply.